# Read CSV file as is in GoLang without creating it a slice

Tags: go

Example: I have a csv file which contains value as:

```
Title,Name,Number,Address
Mr,Shiva,1234,Pune
Mrs,Shivai,123478,Mumbai
```

Need to read this as is in GoLang and should output as:

```
Title,Name,Number,Address
Mr,Shiva,1234,Pune
Mrs,Shivai,123478,Mumbai
```

But when using GoLang's in-built "encoding/csv", it outputs as array:

```
[[Title Name Number Address][Mr Shiva 1234 Pune][Mrs Shivai 123478 Mumbai]]
```

Below is the code I am trying to read CSV

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // os.Open() opens specific file in
    // read-only mode and this return
    // a pointer of type os.File
    file, err := os.Open("CSV_FILE.csv")

    //Check if any error
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error reading CSV: ", err)
    }
    //Closes the file
    defer file.Close()

    // The csv.NewReader() function is called in
    // which the object os.File passed as its parameter
    // and this creates a new csv.Reader that reads
    // from the file
    reader := csv.NewReader(file)
    reader.Comma = ','
    // ReadAll reads all the records from the CSV file
    // and Returns them as slice of slices of string
    // and an error if any
    records, err := reader.ReadAll()

    // Checks for the error
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error reading CSV: ", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(records)
}
```

Can anyone help here please?

Comment: You seem to expect fmt.Println(records) to do some magic and format records exactly as you want in this case. That is a bit much to expect. Just print records the way you want them to be printed. If unsure: Redo the Tour of Go.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `fmt.Println(records)` call `WriteAll`
like below:

```
    w := csv.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
    w.WriteAll(records) 

    if err := w.Error(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("error writing csv:", err)
    }
```

[csv Example](https://go.dev/src/encoding/csv/example_test.go)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped me. Life Saver :)